# EXCEL: Color cell if column is "nth" in the row

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Here is an example excel table

```
Row#   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
  1    Q# Ans   Student Answers
  2    1   4   0   3   1   4   2
  3    2   2   1   7   9   2   0
  4    3   3   5   1   1   3   8
```

Column A stores the question number, Column B is the index of the correct scantron answer (1-5 for A-E).

Columns C-G are sums of the student's answers and how many of them answered each option, so for example:

> Question 2, the correct answer was B (because column B is stored as
>   2). C-G say that 1 student answered A, 7 answered B, 9 answered C, 2
>   answered D and none selected E on the scantron.

With each exam, the values in column B change around. I would like a way to conditionally format columns C-G so that only the nth column is colored (as dictated by whatever the number of A is). So for question 2, it would color the cell at D3 green or something.

I tried to figure this out with conditional formatting, but I can't say if the values match column B, because B is a indicator for which column is correct, not a value to match in each column.

I'm comfortable implementing VBA code, so that works as well, I'm just not familiar enough with it to know how to construct the proper code to insert into my spreadsheet.

Comment: Use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with the [LARGE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) or [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)  function.

Comment: @Jeeped Can you expand on that? I'm not sure how I would use those to make this work. I don't need the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc largest value, or at least I can't see how that helps me pick the proper column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the answer number accross the top of the data in row 1:

[image]

Then you can use the following formula:

```
=MATCH($B2,$1:$1,0)=COLUMN(C2)
```

And apply it to the answer statics area, in this case `$C$2:$G$4`

[image]

---

Or if your answer statistics always follow the Ans column you could use this formula for the same result:

```
=COLUMN($B2)+$B2=COLUMN(C2)
```

Without the need of the title row.

Comment: Simple and works great! I actually have all the student answers in between the answers and the statistics, so the first option works very easily for me :)